# PuLP, groupby columns to see if sum for group is larger than group's threshold

Tags: optimization, nested, nested-loops, linear-programming, pulp

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'id':['6G','4F','2W','1H','7P','3L'],
     'contract': ['contract_1', 'contract_1', 'contract_1', 'contract_2', 'contract_2', 'contract_3'], 
     'thresholds': [.1,.1,.1,.02, .02, .03],
    'performance':[.05,.09,.02,.04,.025,.01],
    'cost':[10,3,2,15,4,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Given the above data, I want to minimize the cost and have a constraint where we want to only pick the id's within the same contract that have a sum of their performance equal to or greater than the threshold.

I am trying to get an output that would then pick the following IDs: ['4F', '2W', '7P']

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'id':['6G','4F','2W','1H','7P','3L'],
     'contract': ['contract_1', 'contract_1', 'contract_1', 'contract_2', 'contract_2', 'contract_3'], 
     'thresholds': [.1,.1,.1,.02, .02, .03],
    'performance':[.05,.09,.02,.04,.025,.01],
    'cost':[10,3,2,15,4,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

from pulp import *
from collections import defaultdict


#list of unique identifiers
contracts_id = list(df['id'])
contract_list = list(df['contract'])

#dictionaries with each unique identifier and its corresponding value for each column
#thresholds = dict(zip(contracts_id,df['thresholds']))
#performance = dict(zip(contracts_id,df['performance']))
#cost = dict(zip(contracts_id,df['cost']))
#contract = dict(zip(contracts_id,df['contract']))

#nested dictionaries with each unique identifier, contract and its corresponding value for each column
thresholds = defaultdict(dict)
for x,y,z in zip(contracts_id,contract_list,df['thresholds']):
    thresholds[x][y]=z
thresholds

performance = defaultdict(dict)
for x,y,z in zip(contracts_id,contract_list,df['performance']):
    performance[x][y]=z
performance

cost = defaultdict(dict)
for x,y,z in zip(contracts_id,contract_list,df['cost']):
    cost[x][y]=z
cost


#find unique contracts

def unique(list1):
    x = np.array(list1)
    return(np.unique(x))
unique_contract_list = unique(contract)
unique_contract_list


contracts_id_chosen = LpVariable.dicts('ID',contracts_id,lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat="Integer")

#setup problem to minimize
total_cost = LpProblem('Min_Cost_Performance_Against_Threshold', LpMinimize)

#objective function
for c in cost:
    total_cost += lpSum([cost[i]*contracts_id_chosen[i] for i in contracts_id_chosen])

#constraint
#I am trying to group by contract and then find which combination of id's performance gets equal to or greater than threshold

for u in list(unique_contract_list):
    for contract_performance in performance.values():
        for c in contract_performance:
            if c==u:    
                total_cost+= lpSum([contract_performance.values()[i]*contracts_id_chosen[i] - thresholds[i] for for i in contracts_id_chosen]) >=0
```

I'm struggling to clearly write the objective function and constraint for this problem. How would you adjust those to group by contract and then find which combination of id's performance gets equal to or greater than threshold when summing the performances.

Comment: I think I understand your problem - except why in your example solution is it OK for contract_3 to not pass its threshold - is there just a number of contracts which need to be selected?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you wish to select some `id`s such that the total cost is minimised, subject to the constraint that the performance for selected ids which belong to each of the contracts at least meet the thresholds for that contract. But that we have some freedom in terms of which contracts we select (I've assumed at least 2 contract have to be selected - as this is case for example solution you gave).

If that is the problem, then this solves it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp as lp

d = {'id':['6G','4F','2W','1H','7P','3L'],
     'contract': ['contr_1', 'contr_1', 'contr_1', 'contr_2', 'contr_2', 'contr_3'],
     'thresholds': [.1, .1, .1, .02, .02, .03],
     'performance':[.05,.09,.02,.04,.025,.01],
     'cost':[10,3,2,15,4,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print(df)

# Declare Problem
model = lp.LpProblem('contract_sel', lp.LpMinimize)

# Which items are picked? (0=no, 1=yes)
items = list(df.index)
x = lp.LpVariable.dicts('x', items, cat=lp.LpBinary)

# Dictionary of contract thresholds:
contracts = {i: v for i, v in zip(df.contract, df.thresholds)}

# Which contracts are picked? (0=no, 1=yes)
y = lp.LpVariable.dicts('y', contracts.keys(), cat=lp.LpBinary)

# Objective - total cost of selected items
model += lp.lpSum(df.loc[i, 'cost']*x[i] for i in items)

# Constraints - items selected from within contract
# have to meet threshold

for contract in contracts.keys():
    contr_items = df[df.contract==contract].index
    model += lp.lpSum(df.loc[i, 'performance']*x[i] for i in contr_items) >= \
            contracts[contract]*y[contract]

# At least two contracts must be selected?
model += lp.lpSum(y[i] for i in contracts.keys()) >= 2

#print(model)

model.solve()
print('Solution status:',lp.LpStatus[model.status])
for v in model.variables():
    print(v.name,': ',v.varValue)

print('Cost is:',lp.value(model.objective))
```

Which returns (for me at least):

```
Solution status: Optimal
x_1H :  0.0
x_2W :  1.0
x_3L :  0.0
x_4F :  1.0
x_6G :  0.0
x_7P :  1.0
y_contr_1 :  1.0
y_contr_2 :  1.0
y_contr_3 :  0.0
Cost is: 9.0
```

Which matches your expected solution: ['4F', '2W', '7P'].